# NodeJS: 'undefined is not a valid uri or options object' with Request

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, cheerio

I'm trying to make a request to a website and scrape a certain value off of each page I have from an array.

The array of all of the links to request is saved into scrapedArr

When I try and run this, I get the error of 'undefined is not a valid uri or options object' at the line `request(newUgcLink, function(error, response, body) {`

```
(code to get scrapedArr)
    message.channel.send(`\`\`\`---------\n${scrapedArr.join('\n')}\`\`\``)
    l = scrapedArr.length
    var newUgcLink;

    do {
        newUgcLink = scrapedArr[l]
        l--;
        request(newUgcLink, function(error, response, body) {
            if (error) {
                throw new Error(error);
                console.log(error);
            }
            var $ = cheerio.load(body);
            var scrapedArr2 = [];
            $(lookfor2).each(function(i, element) {
                var name = $('td:nth-child(3):last-child').text();
                scrapedArr2.push(name);


            });
            console.log(scrapedArr2)
            message.channel.send(`${newUgcLink}: ${scrapedArr2}`);
        })
    }
        while (l > -1)
}}
```

Thanks for the help in advance :)

Edit 1: newUgcLink wasn't defined properly, so I moved the l--; above the line where newUgcLink is declared, but I still get the same error

Edit 2: Silly me! After moving the l--; up, I forgot to change the while statement! Thanks so much to FrankerZ for the help as I don't know how to mark comments as answer :)

Comment: `console.log(newUgcLink)` Make sure `newUgcLink.uri` is defined.

Comment: That's odd, it's undefined... when I put this in my code:

    `console.log("newUGCLink: " + newUgcLink)
    console.log("scrapedArr[l]: " + scrapedArr[l])`

I get:

newUGCLink: undefined
scrapedArr[l]: (the url i should get)

\n\n

Edit: did what FrankerZ suggested and now newUgcLink is defined, but I still get the same error

Comment: Your first iteration will always be undefined. Do `l--;` first in your loop. Javascript arrays are 0 based indexes.